# how to Appserver catch inf from progress

Tags: progress

I'm searching where ASBMAN or ProgressExplorerTools catches this information, in order to build some tiny application toraise alert, charge info for historical issues, and so on

Answer (score 0):

For some things the Virtual Systems Tables are where you should look. They can be found in the documentation (download it from http://communities.progress.com/pcom/index.jspa).

All things are not available there though. Basically you can only find data there about users, database stats, database usage etc.

Specifically you can't find anything about AppServer/WebSpeed brokers and agents etc. Those things are only available by screen scraping it's respective query command. Basic syntax for those:

```
asbman -name <name> -query [-port <port unless default>]
```

or

```
wtbman -name <name> -query [-port <port unless default>]
```